# check checbox programmatically in multiple_choice listview (android)

Tags: android, listview, checkbox, multiple-choice

sorry if there is another question like this but i couldn't find my answer.

I want to know the way to programmatically set a checkbox to state where it is already selected when I populate the **ListView.** The checkbox is in the Listview and i am using `android.R.layout.simple_list_item_multiple_choice.`

Any help would be nice, thank you.

Comment: in this layout its checkedtextview anyway store your checkbox state one array & user checkbox.setChecked(states[pos]); where states will be boolean array

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a method on ListView that you can call to set an item 'checked' state:

```
for (int i = 0; i < getListAdapter().getCount(); i++) {
    getListView().setItemChecked(i, true);
}
```

Comment: You should get the list adapater count once, and also not call getListView() multiple times. Do these prior to the for loop.